Bland-Altman plot for Heart rate measurements (bpm) follow certain 'line' patterns
I'm comparing heart rate measurements of different devices during different periods of activity (5 min resting, 5 min exercise and 5 min recovery).
To analyse the agreement between devices, I want to make Bland Altman plots (using the polar H10 as gold standard).
However, when making a Bland Altman plot of the H10 vs Vantage V3 using the data of all participants, I've noticed some strange line patterns in my plots, and I'm not entirely sure why these occur/what it means?

I've also made plots for each participant, which looks like this:

And when creating the Bland Altman plot for this participant, these line patterns appear:

In a way these lines make sense to me, as you clearly see that when starting the exercise the mean heart rate increases and differences between the devices become larger. And when finishing, the mean heart rate, as well as the differences drop again.
However, in all the papers I've read I don't see such exact line patterns occur, which makes me wonder whether I'm doing something wrong here?
For instance, do I need to exclude certain datapoints or perhaps first do some normalisation?
Any thoughts or help, would be appreciated!

There seems to be some hysteresis between the devices, where the H10 can detect a much sharper increase than the V3 (or FitBit). The difference is less pronounced in recovery because the decrease is more gradual -- for the slower devices the up- and downslopes seem to roughly match. It would be interesting to see how they handle sharper decreases in heart rates, though how to produce those I couldn't say. To me it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong necesarily. Do some of these perhaps return a (longer) running average?

At rest and during recovery, things seem to be OK. No huge differences.  It's during exercise that things are weird. Not only are there big differences between devices, those differences seem different for different people. So ... how do these devices work? Could the exercise be disturbing the devices and might this vary by person? (This could happen, e.g., if they are attached to the body in different places or i different ways).

In the text you mention minutes of exercise, is the period of that peak 5 minutes? What do the labels on the horizontal axis indicate?

@SextusEmpiricus Yes, the frequency differs a bit per device, but for the H10 and V3 it was updated every second or so. The middle peak is indeed the exercise part of 5 minutes. The label on the horizontal axes is the real time (and 13th was the day). So the whole plot is 15 minutes.

@PeterFlom Yes the devices are indeed attached in different ways and use different sensors (the H10 uses ECG, while the other use PPG). Since we already saw that the PPG devices were sensitive to movement, we decided to use a hometrainer during the exercise, so participant were holding their arms stable. But we do indeed see that there are differences between participants..

@PBulls Thanks for you comment. I'm going to look whether I could get my hands on a ECG simulator like suggested below, so using that I could try to see what happens during sharper decreases.

The first comment is the correct explanation. As @PBulls says, there is hysteresis in some devices. In other words, some devices have a large lag in reacting to large changes in heart rate (HR). If you look at the 2nd graph, it is quite apparent.
Now, this is actually a very common feature of any HR algorithm. The algorithm looks for a "signature" of a heart beat (e.g. QRS complex, or some derived signature from it), and updates the HR for every beat. But that HR value is usually "smoothed" (to avoid "noisy" HR readings). Now, the smoothing can go from a basic moving average (over the last $b$ beats, or the last $s$ seconds), to more sophisticated techniques (outlier rejection, trimmed means, median filtering, morphological filters, Kalman filter, etc.). A common such algorithm is the Pan-Tompkins algorithm. The exact details of the methods is not usually disclosed by the manufacturer. Some devices may sometimes allow a user to adjust some of the parameters of this "smoothing".
You can directly evaluate this "lag" by using a ECG simulator; connect it directly to the device under test (DUT), maybe using some coupling gel. Such simulators can instantantly change the HR between 2 constant rates. This will allow you to characterize the "lag". The lag usually depends on the slope of the HR change (large, sudden changes are usually rejected as being "unnatural", while more gradual ones are much less attenuated) and various other factors.
This is why the phenomenon does not occur when the HR is reasonably stable (rest, or late recovery), but is present when the HR changes rapidly (start of exercise, and start of recovery). You even have a device which is so "smoothed" that it never reaches the peak HR.
So nothing wrong with your plot, but maybe something wrong with some devices (possibly all of them; all devices will exhibit some amount of lag, even medical grade EKG recorders; hence the need to estimate this lag with a simulator, even for your "gold standard").

The device that doesn't reach the peak, it seems like that might also be due to errors in the measurements. The initial rise is similar and around 120 bpm it suddenly deviates and not by having a less fast rise, but instead by reaching a seemingly plateau level.

@SextusEmpiricus: quite possibly. Another interesting note is that the "lag" is very obvious for rising HR, but appears to be much smaller (non-=existent?) for decreasing HR? All these are good reason to first characterize HR devices on the bench, with a simulator, to better understand their behaviors, before strapping them on human subjects.

Indeed, the slope of the decrease is stronger than the slope of the increase for both the fitbit and the V3 devices. That shows that these devices can handle fast changes. And if those are minutes instead of seconds on the horizontal axis, then it is not really fast, a hysteresis should be no excuse for a 20 bpm difference after the hearth rate has already been more than a minute roughly constant. The difference in the agreement between the different devices, between exercise versus recovery and rest, can be due to devices measuring or filtering less accurately during exercise circumstances.

@jginestet Thanks for your thorough explanation and suggestion! I'm going to try to get my hands on a ECG simulator.
